# Extract all lines from a file starting with some sequence and then output it to another file

Tags: grep

I have a .csv file with contents similar to this:

```
BIHAR,PURNIA,DAGARUA,BELGACHHI,BELGACHHI,KARBOLA TOLA,0,0,312,0,0,312,Fully Covered,NO,NO,01_04_2010,241656,312,2123,910,1811.5
BIHAR,PURNIA,SRINAGAR,THARI,THARI,ARBANNA,0,0,312,0,0,312,Fully Covered,NO,NO,01_04_2010,244374,312,2123,910,1811.5
BIHAR,PURNIA,RUPAULI,DHOBGIDHA-RUPAULI,DHOBHGIDHA-RUPAULI-II,MATELI,0,0,312,0,0,312,Fully Covered,NO,NO,01_04_2010,243748,312,2123,910,1811.5
ETCETC,PURNIA,KRITYANAND NAGAR,CHUNAPUR,BANBHAG,BANGALI TOLA KOSHI KINARA,0,0,312,0,0,312,Fully Covered,NO,NO,01_04_2010,242663,312,2123,910,1811.5
```

I want to grab all the lines that start with `BIHAR` and then output it to another separate csv file. How do I do that?

I have tried using sublime's "Find All" feature and then use the right arrow to the end of the line to highlight them, but unfortunately some lines are much longer than the others so it doesn't work. There are about 100'000 lines in the .txt file.

I also tried with sed:

```
sed -n 'BIHAR /myfile.txt' /newfile.txt
```

**EDIT: For some reason grep/sed/awk ignores the newlines at the end of each line, and so as a result it only attempts to match the first line and nothing else, how do I fix this?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^BIHAR/p' file > new_file
```

or with grep:

```
grep '^BIHAR' file > new_file
```

or with awk:

```
awk '/^BIHAR/' file > new_file
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I mistyped it's actually a .csv file not a .txt file. As a result the new_file is empty. I have tried your suggestions with a plain text file and it works well! Would you happen to know what to do with a csv?

Comment: Well actually I found the issue, sed/grep/awk doesn't take into account the newline at the end of each line, so it only gets the first thing in the above .csv file and nothing else.

Comment: First remove carriage returns from Windows in your file: `tr -d '\r' < orignal_file > converted_file` or use something like this: `tr -d '\r' < file | grep '^BIHAR' > new_file`

Comment: Hmm it still returns an empty file :(. I tried first removing the carriage return as in the first part of your comment, then doing sed, but what that did is put everything into one giant line in the new file

Comment: Upload your csv file somewhere where I can download it to inspect your file.

Comment: Okay, your file has very long lines, with CR line terminators only. Try this to replace line terminators and write lines starting with BIHAR to new_file: `tr '\r' '\n' < file | sed -n '/^BIHAR/p' > new_file`

Comment: @cyrus, CR-only line terminators are old-style Mac (pre-OSX) text files IIRC

Comment: @cas: Thank you for this useful information.

Answer (score 2):

grep's

```
 grep ^BIHAR file > new_file
```

awk's

```
 awk '/^BIHAR/' file > new_file
```

pedantic awk's

```
 awk -F, '$1 == "BIHAR" { print $0 ;} file > new_file
```

edit: when using file comming from windows world, be sure to use dos2unix to convert end-of-line

```
  dos2unix dosfile > unixfile
```