# How to extract all lines from a file starting with a particular number?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file like this:

```
head logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic
 CHR               SNP         BP   A1       TEST    NMISS         OR         STAT            P 
   2   2:129412140:T:C  129412140    C        ADD     1438      1.523         3.89    0.0001004
  15   15:26411414:G:A   26411414    A        ADD     1438     0.5577       -3.889    0.0001005
   7    7:24286442:T:G   24286442    G        ADD     1438     0.7449       -3.889    0.0001007
   7    7:24286638:G:C   24286638    C        ADD     1438     0.7449       -3.889    0.0001007
   2   2:129403636:T:C  129403636    C        ADD     1438      1.741        3.889    0.0001008
  15   15:70363332:A:G   70363332    G        ADD     1438      1.366        3.886     0.000102
   3    3:13698784:G:A   13698784    A        ADD     1438      1.465        3.884    0.0001028
   3    3:32665882:C:A   32665882    A        ADD     1438       1.54        3.883     0.000103
  12   12:32855080:A:G   32855080    G        ADD     1438      4.013        3.883    0.0001031
```

How do I extract all lines which have 3 in the first column?

I tried this but I got empty file...

```
grep '^3' logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic > logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic_chr3
awk '/^3/' logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic > logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic_chr3
```

For this example the result would be this:

```
  3    3:13698784:G:A   13698784    A        ADD     1438      1.465        3.884    0.0001028
  3    3:32665882:C:A   32665882    A        ADD     1438       1.54        3.883     0.000103
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract all lines from a file starting with some sequence and then output it to another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238522/extract-all-lines-from-a-file-starting-with-some-sequence-and-then-output-it-to)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the first non-whitespace field with the string `3`:

```
awk '$1 == "3"' logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic >logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic_chr3
```

The issue with your commands is that you're expecting the `3` to be the first character on the line, but judging from your sample data, there may be whitespace in front of the number. Using `awk` with its default field delimiter would place the chromosome name in `$1` regardless of leading whitespace characters.

This would also be safer as `$1 == "1"` would only be true for chromosome 1, whereas a regular expression matching `1` at the start of the field (e.g. with `/^[[:blank:]]*1/` or `$1 ~ /^1/`) would also match e.g. `11` and `12`.

Comment: thank you so much for this great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
grep "^[[:blank:]]*3" logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic > logistic_results.assoc_3.logistic_chr3
```